Search for prepayment for an advertising plate on Dexscreener for a coin on the Solana network
import requests
import time
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime
solana_token_addresses = set()
first_run = True  # Флаг для пропуска первого вывода
while True:
try:
    # Выполняем запрос к API
    response = requests.get("https://api.dexscreener.com/token-profiles/latest/v1")
    data = response.json()

    # Проверяем токены и добавляем новые соответствующие условиям
    for token in data:
        if token.get("chainId") == "solana":
            links = token.get("links", [])

            # Проверяем наличие хотя бы одной ссылки на telegram, Website или twitter
            has_relevant_link = any(
                (link.get("type") in ["telegram", "twitter"]) or
                (link.get("label") == "Website") for link in links
            )

            # Если есть ссылки и токен новый, добавляем его в список с отметкой времени
            if has_relevant_link:
                token_address = token["tokenAddress"]
                if token_address not in solana_token_addresses:
                    solana_token_addresses.add(token_address)

                    # Пропускаем вывод, если это первый запуск
                    if not first_run:
                        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                        print(f"[{timestamp}] New Solana Token Address Found: {token_address}")

    # После первого цикла выключаем флаг
    first_run = False

    # Задержка для соблюдения лимита в 60 запросов в минуту
    time.sleep(1)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    time.sleep(1)  # Пауза перед повторной попыткой при ошибке

I am writing a program that allows you to output address tokens to the Solana network, which has a paid fee in Dexcsreener.
The thing is that I used the Dexscreener API, but it provides this information with a delay, or rather, when the plaque appears on the site.
The thing is that there are programs and services that provide information about payments, even if there was an advance payment before arriving at the radium, for example, the token is in the pumpfan.
Perhaps my code is not up-to-date enough, it outputs information, or I am using the wrong API, maybe someone can tell me where I can get information for pre-paying plaques.
